# How many pixels are scrolled on a website with a mouse wheel down event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, dom-events, mouseevent

I'm working on writing a custom scrollbar and am catching the `mousewheel` event. I'm using this to then adjust the scrollTop of the element I want to scroll on.

Is there a standard number of pixels that are scrolled down, or does it vary from system to system?

I'm showing 114px in the latest build of Firefox:

[image]

Comment: There's http://mootools.net/forge/p/scrollspy and http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#scrollspy

Answer (score 11):

Many mouse drivers let you set the distance scrolled by the mouse wheel, so there is not a standard distance.  I'd try your code out for a while and pick a distance that keeps you from scrolling all day but doesn't jump a mile at each scroll.  You'll kind of need to "feel" it out.  Get friends to give feedback, it helps to let a few hands touch this kind of thing.

Comment: I don't think that mouse drivers by themselves are responsible for "the distance scrolled by the mouse wheel". Each mouse wheel event  reports some angle the wheel was rotated. Translation of `WM_MOUSEWHEEL` to `WM_VSCROLL` is a function of GUI subsystem on top of the driver.

Comment: I think @Kirk is trying to determine how far to scroll in pixels, not how far the wheel was turned.

Answer (score 6):

I have noted that in Google Chrome - that is 100px per mouse scroll

Comment: 53px on my PC, also with Chrome (Ubuntu 12.04 LTS).

Comment: 53px here too (Ubuntu 14.04).

Comment: 100px, just like states the answer  -  Environment: Google Chrome 87.0 (year 2020), Windows 7, 1080p

Comment: 4px here on A4Tech N-320 and OSX Catalina

Answer (score 3):

For Firefox, you have the `MozMousePixelScroll` event, which reports the number of pixels that should be scrolled in `e.detail`.

```
window.addEventListener('MozMousePixelScroll', function(e) {
    console.log(e.detail);
});
```

For many other browsers, you have the `mousewheel` event that reports `e.wheelDeltaY`, but they are not in pixels and you will have to guess the amount to be scrolled.

Also see how SproutCore handles scrolling in their own framework (they're writing their own scrolling view too): http://blog.sproutcore.com/scrolling-in-sproutcore/

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to store the current scroll position before the scroll and then when you detect a scroll get the distance travelled me thinks.

Answer (score 0):

We can controll using javascript.
Refer below link. I hope it will help you.

http://deepport.net/archives/javascript-scrolling/

Comment: Looks like you have it set to 5px * the delta value from the mousewheel event there.

Answer (score 0):

Usually each mouse wheel "tick" corresponds to some configurable (by user) number of pixels.

In Windows for example distance scrolled by each mouse wheel click should be a function of 
`SystemParametersInfo( SPI_GETWHEELSCROLLLINES, ...)` parameter.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997498.aspx) you can find more info on the subject.